# Pre-build event fails

Tags: visual-studio, macros, prebuild

I set a prebuild event to:

```
$(TargetDir)MyConsoleApp
```

But when I run the application I get the following output:

```
------ Build started: Project: BlahBlahBlah, Configuration: Debug x86 ------

'd:\users\user\documents\visual' is not recognized as an internal or external 
command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(902,9):
error MSB3073: The command "d:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\
BlahBlahBlah\BlahBlahBlah\bin\Debug\MyConsoleApp" exited with code 9009.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The file MyConsoleApp at the specified target DOES exist and runs properly from windows explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TargetDir variable contains spaces in your case. You need to put quotes around the command:

```
"$(TargetDir)MyConsoleApp"
```

Comment: @Shimmy you add them after the command, outside of the quotes

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely true, I was getting the same error and my parameters did not have a single whitespace character in between. I believe Visual Studio simply gets stumped with these kind of things and wonder why it hasn't been improved in that respect.

In any case, I worked around it by creating a Batch file and then calling that batch file from the Post BUild event with batch file positional parameters:

MyPostBuildCommands.bat $(SolutionDir) $(ProjectDir) $(OutDir)